# Beginner limits in Calc

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, probability-limit-theorems

I got the first part correct(graph) but for the second, is it asking for the values that make y=0? Im confused on this part

[image]

Comment: Looks like only no limit at $x=-1.$ So can't see what is meant by "a comma-separated list".

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to understand this is to think what $x=a$ looks like. It's a vertical line, intersecting the $x$ axis at $a$. Now what does $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ mean? You take your pen, put it on the graph of $f(x)$ close to $a$ and move toward $a$. Find out what the value of $f(x)$ is when you get close to $a$. Then take your pen to the other side of the vertical line and repeat the procedure. If the values when approaching from left or right are not the same, then the limit does not exist. So if you take for example $a=0$, when you approach from left or from right you get the same value: $f(0)=0$. So the limit does exist.